# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src') erro

Tags: jquery, css

I made a dark mode source and it works normally. But when I look at the console window, it says an error. How should I fix it? Below is the dark mode code I wrote.

```
const userTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') let status = false

// Dark and Light Mode on Switch Click document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { const darkSwitch = document.getElementById("switch");

darkSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => { if (status === false) { clickDarkMode() //$('#custom-logo').attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/white-logo.png'); } else if (status === true) { clickLightMode() //$('#custom-logo').attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/color-logo.png'); }

});

if (userTheme === 'dark') {
    clickDarkMode()
} else if (userTheme === 'light') {
    clickLightMode()
}


// 다크/라이트 전환이벤트

function clickDarkMode() { localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark") // darkSwitch.innerText='Light' document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark') document.documentElement.classList.add("darkmode") document.body.classList.add("darkmode") document.getElementById("custom-logo").src = '/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/white-logo.png' status = true }

function clickLightMode() {
localStorage.setItem("theme", "light")
//darkSwitch.innerText='Dark'
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
document.documentElement.classList.remove("darkmode")
document.body.classList.remove("darkmode")
document.getElementById("custom-logo").src = '/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/color-logo.png'
status = false

}

});
```

Comment: url page: https://pumster3.mycafe24.com/

Comment: you don't have anything with an id of `custom-logo` so your get element by id is null - therefore it cannot set src of null